# Select child of clicked item (multiple copies on same page)

Tags: jquery

I want to have a modal pop up when clicking on a person.

I am outputting a CPT on wordpress into a grid. This means that each person's output code is identical. I want to be able to click on each one and have that person's modal pop up.

Currently I have jquery that when you click on one, it pops up all of the modals instead of one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $(‘.staffphoto').click(function(){
        $(‘.staffmodal').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $(‘.close').click(function(){
        $(‘.staffmodal').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapcenter staff">
    <div class="staffphoto" data-id="[wpbb post:id]">[wpbb post:featured_image size="large" display="tag" linked="no"]</div>
    <h3 class="staffname">[wpbb post:title]</h3>
    <p class="stafftitle">[wpbb post:pods_display field='job_title']</p>


    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="staffmodal" class="staffmodal" data-id="[wpbb post:id]">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="staff-modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="staffwrapper">
            [wpbb post:featured_image size="large" display="tag" linked="yes"]
            <div class="staffinfomodal">
                <h3 class="staffnamemodal">[wpbb post:title]</h3>
                <p class="stafftitlemodal">[wpbb post:pods_display field='job_title']</p>
                <p class="staffbio">[wpbb post:pods_display field='bio']</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So in summary, I need to be able to display just the modal of the photo that someone clicks. Here is the test page I'm trying it on: https://pyledigital.com/test-staff

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I have added matching data-ids to both the clicked element and the modal. I'm assuming this is the right direction, but still not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.staffphoto').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('.wrapcenter.staff');
    $('.staffmodal[data-id]', parent).show();
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.staffmodal').hide();
});
```